# Can you make a dynamically typed HtmlHelper extension in Asp.Net MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am attempting to make a dynamically typed extension HtmlHelper, but I am getting and error.  For example, if I try this:

```
public static string DropDownWithAdder<T>(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    return "Test Worked";
}
```

And this in the View:

```
@Html.DropDownWithAdder<Code>()
```

I get the error

> CS1061:
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'DropDownWithAdder' and no extension
>   method 'DropDownWithAdder' accepting a
>   first argument of type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

But if I simply remove the <T> it works just fine.  My question is can you use a generic typing in an Html extension method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extension method needs to take the Html helper object as its first parameter

```
public static string DropDownWithAdder<T>(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    return "Test Worked";
}
```

Edit:

You also need to surround the call in brackets to prevent Razor interpreting the < as the start of an html tag:

@(Html.DropDownWithAdder())

Comment: You might need @(Html.DropDownWithAdder<Code>()) so that razor doesn't interpret the < as the start of a tag